# Argument parsing inside a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to parse arguments that look something like `test -t 5 -m hello` or `test --time 5 --message hello`. I've done some research and found out about [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), but as far as I know, this module only accepts command line arguments. I, however, want it to parse the arguments in the same way, but instead they are stored inside a string.

Does anybody of you know of a way to do this?

Comment: what is your desired result? [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html?highlight=shlex#module-shlex) can split such strings...

Comment: Consider having whatever generates the string generate a list instead, so that you don't have to rely on `shlex` to parse it for you.

Comment: The string is generated by a library that is unable to output as a list, so I'll have to parse it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `argparse` module and [explicitly pass arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) to `parse_args()`. You will first split your string into individual arguments with `shlex.split()`.

Comment: `.split()` won't deal with quoted and escaped spaces.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough. But `shlex.split()` will.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take a look at the  `argparse` module, which do what you are looking for.

If you are using python < 3.2, then the module is `optparse`, which is then  deprecated from newwer versions